# Choosing a <DIV> to update dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that creates a table, each cell of which contains a  with an id of row number + "," + column_number (e.g. the top-left cell is built with:

```
<td><div id="0,0">This is 0,0</div></td>
```

).  I want to be able to modify a cell's contents within the code without having to refresh the entire page, but I can't figure out how to update a particular  by ID dynamically.  When I do something like this:

```
var row = 1;
var col = 1;
var newCellContents = "This cell is changed";
var divID = row.toString() + "," + col.toString();
$(divID).html(newCellContents);
```

it throws a syntax error; I assume it is trying to find a div named "divID".

How would I get it to update the div with ID "1,1"?

Comment: Where is the syntax error?  You've *drastically* changed your code since originally posting the question.

Comment: Note that commas may not be valid `id` values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @David in HTML5 they are valid (in fact anything but a space is valid in an `id`) however the sizzle engine that jQuery uses expects `,` to be a delimiter so they need to be escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you'll need to escape the comma in the selector, otherwise it will be interpreted as a separator between selectors instead of part of the `id` value. To do that, precede the comma with `\\`. You will also need to prepend a `#` to the selector so that it searches for elements by `id`. Try this:

```js
var row = 1;
var col = 1;
var newCellContents = "This cell is changed";
var divID = row.toString() + "\\," + col.toString(); // note the use of \\

$('#' + divID).html(newCellContents);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="0,0">This is 0,0</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="1,1">This is 1,1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Got it - put # in front of the id to indicate the variable value is to be used.  Also, I changed the separator from "," to "_" and it works without having to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

you have forgottten the `#` for to access the id

```
var divID = '#' + row.toString() + "," + col.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different separator that doesn't require escaping. There are numerous special characters that do

See [jQuery selector escaping](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Note that concatenating numbers with strings will automatically coerce them to string

```js
var row = 1;
var col = 1;
var newCellContents = "This cell is changed";
var divID = row + "_" + col;
$('#' + divID).html(newCellContents);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="0_0">This is 0,0</div>
<div id="1_1">This is 1,1</div>
```